# Why do 2 exact same pages render fonts differently from each other?

Tags: css

These are two pages, exactly the same. Have exact same bare bones Apache config and same home directory on same server. Page has just 1 sentence of text with no styles. In Chrome and Safari, the fonts render differently from one another, while when using Microsoft Edge they seem to render the same. Confused about why they render differently from each other in Chrome and Safari.

http://www.santamariarealty.com/
http://www.floridarealestate-homes.com/

Exact same bare bones Apache Configs except for the domain name:

VirtualHost *:80
DocumentRoot /mydir/home_dir
ServerName www.floridarealestate-homes.com
ServerAlias floridarealestate-homes.com
/VirtualHost

VirtualHost *:80
DocumentRoot /mydir/home_dir
ServerName www.santamariarealty.com
ServerAlias santamariarealty.com
/VirtualHost

Comment: Appearing the same on Chrome here.  Pehaps you have CSS cached for one of those domains?

Comment: You need to include a [mcve] in the question directly, otherwise this question is [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic). Linking to off-site resources is discouraged as they are subject to change. If those sites are fixed later, this question ceases to be helpful to any future visitors.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Now I can see it's a browser caching issue. The cache is stubborn. In Chrome (Windows 10) I went to 'more tools>', 'Clear Browsing Data...', delete 'Cached Images and FIles' from 'Beginning of Time'. Then I restarted browser and the cached content is still there.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't hosting the fonts on the site you linked, so it will only show what is on your computer. If you have the .eot version of the font file for example, it will appear in IE, otherwise, it will render whatever the default font is for that browser.

If you don't know how to package fonts for web, I would strongly recommend using this tool or something equivalent, as it will auto-generate the necessary CSS and font files for you.

https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator